# C++ curl post timing out at curl_easy_perform

Tags: c++, curl, libcurl

Quite new to c++ and all of this so sorry for any awful awful mistakes that I may make.

I have a post function that I use to send data to a website and then returns other data to me.
The problem is that it times out at curl_easy_perform
Here's my source.
It was working not too long ago but it stopped for some weird reason. I can assure you that it is not the website as I've tried with many others.

```
size_t WriteCallback(char *contents, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userp)
{
    ((std::string*)userp)->append((char*)contents, size * nmemb);
    return size * nmemb;
}

string post(string source) {
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;
    string readBuffer;
    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl) {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "mywebsite");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE, source.length());
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, source.c_str());
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteCallback);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &readBuffer);

        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        cout << res << endl;
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
        return readBuffer;

    }
    curl_global_cleanup();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I put it there just incase it wasn't working because of the postfieldsize. Whether it's there or not didnt change anything. It's still timing out

Comment: Did you verify that the URL is accessible in a browser and doesn't timeout there? Did you try using a network sniffer to see what kind of response Curl is receiving, if any?

Comment: It doesn't seem like it's receiving any responses.

Comment: I changed it right after testing and can confirm nothing different happened sadly.

Comment: I said that I removed it after testing and nothing changed. It still times out. It doesn't change anything at all sadly. Exactly nothing is different.

Comment: Ah my bad. I already changed it in my IDE but I just edited my post to be sure nobody gets confused again. I'm still looking for a solution to my problem though.

Comment: Follow what Remy said. Actually investigate the network transaction using a packet sniffer (e.g. Wireshark) or somesuch. Then if you can prove the network and website are fine, present a [mcve] of your Curl code.

Comment: The problem _may_ be in the `WriteCallback` function that we can't see.

Comment: Added the WriteCallback function in the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. Turns out something was wrong with how I initialized my console and main functions which I don't quite understand. Thanks anyways!